# Show the Lebesgue-measure of the image of the Cantor-Function is equal to 1?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions, cantor-set

Currently strugging to proof the following:

Let f be the Cantor-Function defined as the limit of affine functions (so not the definition with base 3), C the cantor set and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Show that $$\lambda (f(C)) = 1$$

I have already proven that C is negligible but I don't really know how that helps me in this case.

Comment: Hint: $f$ is constant on the complement of the Cantor set, and $m(f([0,1]))=1$.

Comment: @kieransquared Whats the reason for $m(f([0,1])) = 1$? Because we are adding infinitely many intervals of length $2^{-n}$?

Comment: @Zedssad hint:  what does the intermediate value theorem tell you about $f([0,1])$?

Comment: @kieransquared I think I see what you're getting at: $1 = m(f([0,1])) = m(f(C \cup ([0,1] \setminus C) = m(f(C) \cup f([0,1] \setminus C) = m(f(C)) + m(f([0,1] \setminus C)$. And since f is constant on $f([0,1] \setminus C$ which is the union of countable many intervals it's negligible?

Comment: Meant constant on $[0,1] \setminus C$

Comment: Yes, precisely.